# wordpress- trouble in function

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with this code:

```
<?php 
    if (is_home()) $args=array(
        'showposts'=> (int) get_option('13floor_homepage_posts'),
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'category__not_in' => (array) get_option('13floor_exlcats_recent'),
    ); 
?>
```

I am unable to find this term: `13floor_homepage_posts` in the whole theme file. From the codex I have found about `get_option`

> A safe way of getting values for a named option from the options database table. If the desired option does not exist, or no value is associated with it, FALSE will be returned."

After that I've searched in the wordpress database but could not find `13floor_homepage_posts` and `13floor_exlcats_recent`

Can anyone please explain this to me

Comment: Did you look in your functions.php?

Comment: i have added the full theme in dreamweaver site , but no result

Answer (score 0):

The [`get_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) method in WordPress will query the `{wp-prefix}_options` table for a row with the key supplied, in your case '13floor_homepage_posts'. As you stated from the documentation if not found then `FALSE` is returned, this means if you queried your options table and did not find it then the response will be false. Which in the case of the code snippet you posted I assume will be running against a post query and the `showposts` parameter when set to false will show all posts. So if your theme has an admin console/configuration section I assume it will also have a way to set the value as a setting.

As an asside, considering the fact that the code is using `showposts` instead of its replacement `posts_per_page` I assume this theme might be a bit dated when it comes to the code and compatibility with newer versions of WordPress/